# Changing drive location with btrfs- raid5

Tags: btrfs

A file system of three hard drives is formatted in Raid 5 with btrfs. The server has 4 slots: 0, 1, 2 are busy. Now I want to put another drive in 0, because the server should boot from it. Can I simply plug the existing drive into slot 3? Of course, the file system should survive.
Shutting down is possible. The filesystem ist implemented via btrfs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that

- "formatted in Raid 5 with btrfs" means your RAID5 is implemented by Btrfs (as opposed to Btrfs on top of LVM or hardware RAID5);
- "plug the existing drive into slot 3" means "remove it from slot 0 and plug into slot 3";
- your BIOS (or anything else that starts before the OS: UEFI, HDD controller BIOS, bare metal hypervisor etc.) will expose the disk from slot 3 to your OS in a similar way it now exposes it from slot 0.

If so, the filesystem should survive. Shutdown, move the disk, boot.

When your OS starts, it scans block devices (`btrfs device scan`, see `man 8 btrfs-device`). If two (or more) devices contain Btrfs signatures and report identical UUIDs, they are considered to hold a single multi-device Btrfs filesystem. You formally mount any of them and the entire filesystem is mounted because after scanning the kernel knows where to find the rest of it.

So after you change slots from 0 to 3, it shouldn't matter to Btrfs. All the devices will be scanned at boot and the whole filesystem ready to mount.

Other problems may arise, e.g.:

- if booting depends on the drive you moved, you may need to update the config afterwards;
- if you mount by paths like `/dev/sda` (or you use such paths for anything else), this may break because it's possible the OS will enumerate devices differently (therefore it's way better to mount by UUID).

These problems neither are related to Btrfs nor directly threaten your Btrfs filesystem.

Comment: I changed the drives. Everything works as aspected. Drives mounted by UUID. A very accurate answer.